# What is the element to the Blue META banner/footer?

Tags: support, design

I am trying to write an extension for meta.stackexchange.com that would allow me to change the colors and theme it locally.

I was trying to go through the element picker in developer tools and I am having trouble finding the right element, it is hidden really well. Unless I am missing something, the blue and white are a single image.

I really hope that isn't the case and hopefully I can change CSS or do an image replace (thinking out loud).

Maybe there is a better way to which I am unaware of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the background of the container:

```
.container {
    background: #FFF url(img/bg-site.png?v=ddf9bb38a2bf) left -37px repeat-x;
}

#footer {
    background-image: url(img/icon-cloud-footer.png?v=ac80a4525ace),url(img/bg-site.png?v=ddf9bb38a2bf);
    background-position: left bottom,left top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat,repeat;
    background-size: 475px 280px,63px 180px;
}
```

[Direct Link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/content/Sites/stackexchangemeta/img/bg-site.png?v=ddf9bb38a2bf)

Comment: wow! how did you find it so quick! Impressed :)

Comment: @DeerSpotter Right click -> Inspect -> Look at the css.  Where were you looking for the images?  In the HTML itself?

Comment: I also saw this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/content/Sites/stackexchangemeta/img/bg-site.png?v=ddf9bb38a2bf

Comment: @JAL yeah, sadly that's what i did. I dont have too much css experience.

Comment: @DeerSpotter Right, that image is tiled and there are additional images laid out on top of it.  See the "cloud" of logos for example: https://meta.stackexchange.com/content/Sites/stackexchangemeta/img/icon-cloud@2.png?v=2f4838039b7f

Comment: So it looks like i will have to do a element replace, which i what i actually wanted to do. Thanks!